# Disable multiple key with 1 script

Tags: javascript

I want to disable TAB & ENTER key. I can do it in separate script like below:

```js
<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
  e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();}
});
</script>

<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
  e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();}
});
</script>
```

How to combine it become just 1 script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Logical Operator **[`OR ||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)** operator which will check for both conditions as below

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 ||  e.keyCode === 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store all your disabled key in an array and use [`array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the `e.keyCode` value is present in the array.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    const disabledKey = [13,9];
    if (disabledKey.includes(e.keyCode)){
        e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();}
});
```